# Don't know if HR has taken my complaint seriously

Tags: harassment

I sent the company an email about harassment regarding another employee at the company. I wanted to do it as anonymously as possible so I just used a throwaway email account and emailed the email they list in the 'contact us' page. I included a ton of evidence. This employee is harassing other members of the company as well. I haven't received an email back. Normally, whenever you email them via their 'contact us' email, they respond within 24 hours. Does this mean that they are ignoring my email? What are some other steps I can take to ensure they are investigating, while also maintaining my anonymity?

Update (in case anyone actually cares): they received the message and they didn't ignore my complaint

Comment: Why did you want to do it anonomously?

Comment: because the person who is doing this is very retaliatory and I don't know what he would do or say. plus, he is harassing so many people that I don't think he could narrow it down to me this way. I'm concerned because he clearly makes money for the company. so I don't know if they're just protecting him.

Comment: also I should make clear that he's harassing people online as well. he has revealed company information online. he has leaked emails between him and other female colleagues and made sexual comments about them in the captions. He has revealed his performance review and made derogatory comments about his boss. he's posted several photos online of his different bosses and said horrible slurs and comments about them

Comment: I have a feeling that he would deny doing this however idk how much the company would care. even if he denies it, there's information that only he would have.

Comment: We can't tell you what your HR department is doing. Maybe they're ignoring it, maybe they have engaged lawyers and have been advised not to respond, maybe something else.

Comment: Potentially HR is your friend in this case, as if this person is a bad as you say, then the cost of a lawsuit against the company is likely more than the cost of ditching this person.    But where are you?

Comment: Would it actually help if they responded with "ok, we are looking into it?" Or would you be complaining that that's all they said and might not be doing anything.

Comment: @Studoku okay that's a fair point. I guess I'm just anxious about the whole situation, which is causing me to speculate on things I have no control over

Comment: @PeterM The legality of this depends a lot on location. Unfortunately there are still may countries where this type of behavior is commonplace with few or no viable legal options.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well I did it so that I could stay as anonymous as possible. Do you think I should email HR specifically? or Legal? I sent the email two days ago. I don't know what's been happening since then. So there's a chance they'd think 'uh we're already investigating, why tf is this person sending it again?'

Comment: @Hilmar the company is based in chicago, with locations in amsterdam. And I'm in amsterdam, and the coworker is also in amsterdam

Comment: A lot will depend on the functioning of the "contact us" link. It's probably set up for either sales enquiries or maybe job inquiries, and regular inquiries will be handled quickly. But is it going to a specialist department with dedicated staff, or is it going to some administrator with lots of other functions? A big company might have procedures for this, but a lot of companies will have no clue and it might be waiting in a queue or just getting deleted out of panic.

Comment: @StuartF is right. You need to find a better means of anonymous reporting. Perhaps your email went into a long queue or the spam box. Try instead to contact HR's email. Also, how did you make a throwaway account? If you used a disposable email client, then your email may have gone directly to spam.

Comment: Since you're based in the Netherlands, your company is legally required to have one or more designated ["vertrouwenspersonen"](https://www.arboned.nl/wat-u-moet-weten/verzuim-verlagen/vertrouwenspersoon) exactly for these types of issues. Have you considered discussing this with them?

Comment: thanks for the update @user8358234 !!!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - that was really fascinating, thanks!  (I just read it w/ goog-translate)

Comment: The OP shouldn't deface their post. By deleting the context and the original content, they are invalidating the upvoted answer, this is disrespectful to the author who spent time in composing their answer and to the everyone else that has  to now look at the edit history to understand what happened.

Answer (score 16):

> I haven't received an email back.

Why would they e-mail you back? What do you expect to hear? You have submitted your feedback anonymously, i.e. you made it quite clear that you personally want to stay out of the situation.

The company may choose to deal with that or not in whatever way they feel is best for them. However, this is none of your business and it's legally much smarter for them to leave you out of it as much as possible. Since you are anonymous, they need to independently verify any evidence & claims anyway since they can't use yours. As far as they know this could be real or you could just be a disgruntled employee.

> What are some other steps I can take to ensure they are investigating, while also maintaining my anonymity?

Not a whole lot. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: You make good points. You're right, they have no reason to respond to me. I think I'm just nervous and scared that since I sent it anonymously, they won't take it seriously. And yes, they would independently verify what I say in my email but I also sent them a link to his tumblr where he says all of these horrible things about people. Would they contact tumblr to find out more information?

Comment: Also, since I sent it anonymously and to their 'contact us' email, I wonder if they would actually think I'm an employee. Since I could've anonymously sent it to people within the company or HR. I sent it to the contact us email because I thought it would be more anonymous that way. Instead of people speculating who I know in HR, or them potentially speculating on who i am

Comment: As far as they are concerned you could easily be a troll trying to make trouble for the company, and any response from HR could potentially be used against the company.

Comment: @DJClayworth yeah I understand but given the nature of the accusations, I would assume they are required to at least take them seriously. And while i mentioned this to them anonymously, I did share his tumblr. And on that tumblr you can clearly see him harass others. And he posted his performance review (which only he would have access to) and he posted email exchanges between him and other coworkers (which could be verified by the coworkers)

Comment: @DJClayworth true, he can deny making the tumblr, but even if he does deny making the tumblr, no doubt that a lot of stuff is coming from his phone and is his.. do you think they would contact tumblr to get more information? I mean I know that I could just be a troll, but why would a troll go so far as to fabricate all of these posts going back to 2016

Comment: If you have specific evidence like that they *may* take it seriously, although you could be faking it. Even if they take it seriously they will probably not respond to you, the anonymous complainer.

Comment: I'm sure they could verify whether or not those are his actual performance reviews right? Or they could verify whether or not he did sent those emails to other colleagues. and if he did, how would someone else get access to them? he could say he was hacked but if he was hacked he should have proof of that. and in any case, the emails are relatively mild. it's the captions that he puts underneath them. he also writes work-related posts about things he's doing at work, they could check and see if that was in fact what he was doing

Comment: @DJClayworth I guess I just don't understand why someone's initial reaction would be that this is a troll instead of taking it seriously. Isn't that the job of HR, to take things seriously? If he's admitting to drugging women and posting all these horrible things on his tumblr, don't they at least have a responsibility to take it seriously. isn't there more of a liability to just assuming it's a troll?

Comment: I'm just concerned now that since I sent it anonymously, they're going to assume this whole thing is some sort of trolling.

Comment: @user8358234 take a deep breath and wait 48 hours. Do your job and behave as you normally would at work. Don't "gossip" to anyone and avoid any snooping attempts that will only draw attention to yourself.